# How capture messages of WS/Socket url from network with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sockets, ws

I want capture message of bellow image with javascript or jquery

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6pHD.png

[image]

How can I?

This code not work for me:

```
var wsUri = "wss://****";
var output;

function init()
{
  output = document.getElementById("output");
  testWebSocket();
}

function testWebSocket()
{
  websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
  websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
  websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
  websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
  websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
}
```

Comment: This does not quite follow the guidelines of how to ask a question on stackoverflow. Do you think you could provide some more information of what you are trying to do please?

Comment: @JohanJarvi I add url of image. sorry

Comment: Have you read through the Mozilla developer documentation for websockets in JS?

Here's a link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

There's a code example toward the end of the article that might help you debug your issues.

Comment: @JohanJarvi thank you. but I dont want use URL. I want capture anything in message of network tab

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood what you are actually trying to achieve. So I guess what you want to create is essentially a network sniffer using JavaScript. In which case my knowledge is somewhat limited unfortunately. Are you attempting to do this through a frontend browser based application? Most examples I can find online seem to do this kind of thing Server-side with NodeJS/Express etc.